Two incarnations of $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebras
There are two different descriptions of an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra that one commonly finds in the literature:

One is an algebra over the little cubes operad $\mathbb{E}_n$, where $\mathbb{E}_n$ is the topological operad which level-wise consists of rectilinear embeddings of cubes, and an algebra is an operad map $\mathbb{E}_n \to \mathrm{End}_A$ from $\mathbb{E}_n$ to the endomorphism operad $\mathrm{End}_A$ where $A$ is an object of a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$.

The other is a symmetric monoidal ($\infty$?)-functor from the category $\mathrm{Disks}_n$ of $n$-disks and embeddings to a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$.


How are the two approaches exactly related? And in particular, how is it handled the fact that we allow only rectilinear embeddings in the first description and all embeddings in the second one?

Your question is naturally split in two parts. First, one can consider two variants of the little cubes operad: the rectilinear embeddings or all framed embeddings. There is an obvious inclusion of the first into the second which is a map of operads, and it is easily seen to be an equivalence because both are homotopy equivalent to the configurations of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The second part of your question is about the relation between symmetric monoidal functors out of the category of framed disks and $E_n$-algebras. Such categories are equivalent because if one applies the envelope construction to the framed disks operad one obtains the category of framed disks. This is in fact the characterizing property of the envelope. More explicitly, the object $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the disk category is canonically an $E_n$-algebra, and the push forward of this under symmetric monoidal functors yields all $E_n$-algebras.

(1) By "equivalence" you mean "weak homotopy equivalence"? (2) By "symmetric monoidal functor" you mean of ordinary categories or $\infty$-categories? (3) Do you know a reference where this is explained in more detail?

@Minkowski (1) Yes, at the model categorical level this is a weak homotopy equivalence and since these aren't cofibrant operads there isn't a reason it should have an inverse. (2) This is true in both cases and is only subtle at the $\infty$-categorical level. (3) I would generally point you to arxiv.org/pdf/2106.12975 to learn about symmetric monoidal categories of models of operads which uses §2.2.4 of Higher Algebra which is more relevant to your question. At the 1-categorical level it is easy to identify the envelope of the framed little disks operad with the symmetric monoidal category of

framed embeddings of disks. It should be rather formal that including strict operads into $\infty$-operads commutes with the envelope construction which allows you to conclude the result for $E_n$-algebras in the $\infty$-categorical world.

Thank you for your clear answer and comments. The only point that I haven't understood yet is what exactly the relation between the categories of algebras over the two version of the $E_n$ operad (which are weak homotopy equivalent) is. Are they equivalent categories?

@Minkowski If you consider them as $\infty$-operads, their $\infty$-categories of algebras agree. The $1$-categories of algebras are certainly not the same, but they might present the same $\infty$-category after inverting weak equivalences, though I doubt there is a formal argument, since neither is cofibrant.
